# No unit-test result in Power Query M

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to write a custom connector for Power BI, in Visual Studio Code, using power query M, and I am trying to write some unit-test for it.

Following the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/handling-unit-testing

```
shared MyExtension.UnitTest =
[
    TestAccessToken = "nkls8CDwDZZGmjFFDrPFI64X",
    TestStartTime = "2020-09-13T00:00:00Z",
    TestEndTime = "2023-06-13T00:00:00Z",
    TestEndpoint = "Events",
    result = API.GetRecords(TestEndpoint, TestStartTime,TestEndTime),
    facts =
    {
        Fact("Check that we have three entries in our nav table", 3, Table.RowCount(result))
    },
    report = Facts.Summarize(facts)
][report];
```

However when I run this in Visual Studio Code, I get the following results:

```
[12:37:57 PM]   [Info]  RunTestBattery result [
    {
        "ActivityId": "042c992f-409e-49ff-9e7a-fe70477fad69",
        "DataSourceAnalysis": [
            ...
        ],
        "Details": "MyExtension.UnitTest",
        "EndTime": "2023-05-05T19:37:57.4942915+00:00",
        "Method": "MyExtension.UnitTest",
        "Name": "API.query.pq",
        "StartTime": "2023-05-05T19:37:55.0417748+00:00",
        "Output": [
            {
                "Result": null,
                "Notes": null,
                "Details": null
            },
            {
                "Result": null,
                "Notes": null,
                "Details": null
            }
        ],
        "RowCount": 2,
        "Status": "Passed",
        "Type": "PQTest.RunTest"
    }
]
```

How come there is no test results?